# Search between two times (e.g. 14:00:00 - 16:00:00)

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone here tell me how to write code to search for a time.
For example in my database, I have `start_time` and `end_time` like this:

```
start_time   end_time
14:00:00     16:00:00
```

I have php code to search for it if I put in the text field to find for the time `14:00:00` to `16:00:00`, but

My question is how can I get the same result if user search for the time between it ?

For example, if user search for the time `15:00:00 to 16:00:00`.

sorry for my english..hope anybody can help me..thank you.

below is my code.

FORM

```
      <input name="intime" type="time" placeholder='Insert Time'>
      <input name="intime2" type="time" placeholder='Insert Time'>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="SEARCH" />

      </form>
```

Comment: $query = "SELECT start_time,end_time
 from reservation where start_time like '%$intime%' AND end_time like '%$intime2%' " ;

Comment: how can i add the code that you give just now to my code above James Lalor?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking for times between two times, we can use the AND clause in our Query, utilising more than (and equal to) with less than (and equal to) - This returns results equal to the two form inputs (intime and intime2) as well as the results inbetween them.

```
WHERE time >= $intime AND time <= $intime2
```

As for what you're asking, have you tried...

```
$intime = (isset($_POST['intime']) ? $_POST['intime'] : 0);
$intime2 = (isset($_POST['intime2']) ? $_POST['intime2'] : 0);

$query = "SELECT start_time, end_time FROM reservation WHERE" . 
    ($intime ? " start_time >= '%$intime%'" : "") . 
    ($intime && $intime2 ? " AND" : "") .
    ($intime2 ? " end_time <= '%$intime2%'" : "");
```

Comment: Updated with somewhat more info, good explanations are not my forte.

Comment: $query = "SELECT start_time,end_time from reservation where start_time like '%$intime%' AND end_time like '%$intime2%' " ;

Comment: how can i add the code that you give just now to my code above James Lalor?

Comment: `SELECT start_time, end_time from reservation where start_time >= '%$intime%' AND end_time <= '%$intime2%'`

Comment: I get a result "Result not found". i dont know why..to post i make the coding like this.
if (isset($_POST['intime'])) 
{
 $intime=$_POST['intime'];
}else
$intime=0;




if (isset($_POST['intime2'])) 
{
 $intime2=$_POST['intime2'];
}else
$intime2=0;   Is that a correct way?

Comment: I didn't space it correctly, try the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

where time between start_time and end_time;